# Which Ajax option should I use in case of getting the large view result?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance

When using `Ajax` in ASPNET MVC, I have 4 options to get *view result* at least (attached code below).

As a result, Which should I use over the other ones? In the case of the large data, I don't want to get the error msg like

> [*Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
> JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
> on the maxJsonLength property.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config).

Note that, the [`Json option (3 or 4)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694621/ajax-and-asp-net-mvc-should-i-use-partialview-or-json) can give us *"Binding on the client-side is going to be faster than the performance hit of the extra network hit"* benefits aspect as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694621/ajax-and-asp-net-mvc-should-i-use-partialview-or-json) said.

---

1. **PartialView - HttpGet**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AjaxRequest]
    public PartialViewResult GetTemporaryInvoices(GetTemporaryInvoicesCriteria criteria)
    {
        var data = _multipleInvoicesGenerationService.GetTemporaryInvoices(criteria);
        return PartialView("~./InvoicesTable_Content.cshtml", data);
    }
```

2. **PartialView - HttpPost**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AjaxRequest]
    public PartialViewResult GetTemporaryInvoices(GetTemporaryInvoicesCriteria criteria)
    {
        var data = _multipleInvoicesGenerationService.GetTemporaryInvoices(criteria);
        return PartialView("~./InvoicesTable_Content.cshtml", data);
    }
```

3. **Json - HttpGet**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AjaxRequest]
    public JsonResult GetTemporaryInvoices(GetTemporaryInvoicesCriteria criteria)
    {
        var jsonData = _multipleInvoicesGenerationService.GetTemporaryInvoices(criteria);
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

4. **Json - HttpPost**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AjaxRequest]
    public JsonResult GetTemporaryInvoices(GetTemporaryInvoicesCriteria criteria)
    {
        var jsonData = _multipleInvoicesGenerationService.GetTemporaryInvoices(criteria);
        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u use multiple actions from your view page then go for **Json - HttpGet
(option 3)**. This will help you to get the data without reloading the view page and get the data from the server-side. I have used this before for getting a large number of data but you should improve your LINQ getting data method on the manager.

**NB: In the localhost run, it looks slower but when you put your solution on the production server then it will be faster than before.**